# Building a chat app with angular, trying to make it so whenever the @ character is typed a list of the groups users appears above the @ symbol

Tags: angular

So say I've got an input as follows:

```
<input 
class="chatInput form-control" 
[(ngModel)]="message" 
(keydown)="handleSubmit($event)"
/>
```

as well as a list of group members with username attributes.

I want to make it so similar to `groupme`, every time I type the **@** symbol, a list of the groups users pop up above wherever the @ is. I'm able to identify WHEN there is an @ symbold typed with `(ngModelChange)`, however I don't know how to make a pop up at the exact location of the @ symbol. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend to go from scratch, because of browser handling, screen sizes keyboard control, debounceTime etc.

Why don't you try it with angular material. This Stackblitz may help you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4tkhtg-idm9tv?file=src/app/autocomplete-filter-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can something like:

```
<input 
class="chatInput form-control" 
[(ngModel)]="message" 
(keydown)="handleSubmit($event)"
/>
<ul class="list-group" ng-model="users" ng-hide="!users">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">{{user.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

This will show a list of users just below your input, like this:

[image]

Hope this will help you.